# Set VB.NET variable to C#'s null

Tags: c#, vb.net, null

According to the [MSDN entry for Nothing (Visual Basic)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0x9tb07z.aspx)

> **Nothing** represents the default value of a data type.

It has also been noted by [some](http://blog.slaks.net/2010/12/nothing-vs-null.html) that "...the `Nothing` keyword is actually equivalent to C#’s [`default(T)`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xwth0h0d.aspx) keyword".

This has been giving me some anomalous behaviour in a multi-language solution I have been working on recently. Specifically I have been getting with more than a few `TargetInvocationException`s being thrown at the C# end when the VB.NET async methods return `Nothing`.

Is it possible to set a variable in the VB.NET projects to C#'s `null` and be able to test for this `null` value in both C# and VB.NET.

---

Here is a snippet that is not behaving as expected. The C# project imports the VB.NET project as a reference.

**VB.NET Side**

```vb
Public Function DoSomething() As Task(Of Object)
    Dim tcs = New TaskCompletionSource(Of Object)
    Dim params = Tuple.Create("parameters", tcs)

    AnotherMethod(params)

    Return tcs.Task
End Function

Public Sub AnotherMethod(params As Tuple(Of String, TaskCompletionSource(Of Object))
    ' do some activities
    If result = "Success" Then
        params.Item2.SetResult("we were successful") ' result can also be of different type
    Else
        params.Item2.SetResult(Nothing)  ' could this be the source of the exception?
    End If
End Sub
```

**C# Side**

```cs
public async void AwaitSomething1()
{
    var result = "";
    result = (await DoSomething()).ToString(); // fails if Result is Nothing
}

public async void AwaitSomething2()
{
    var result = "";
    result = (string)(await DoSomething());    // fails if Result is Nothing
}

public async void AwaitSomething3()
{
    var task = DoSomething();
    await task;                                // also fails if Result is Nothing
}
```

There is no exception thrown when VB.NET's `AnotherMethod` is successful. However, when it is not successful and `tcs`'s result is set to `Nothing`, everything falls on its head.

How can I effectively `SetResult` to `Nothing` without resulting in an exception or, otherwise, how can I `SetResult` to C#'s `null`?

Comment: You mean you get an exception on the `ToString()` call because the return value of `await DoSomething()` is null?

Comment: i could be wrong,  but on the c# side it looks like your trying to pass a null value to the `.ToString()`  Which could result in a "null value" error being thrown,  alternativly give us the erorr your getting "falls on it's head" isn't as informative as "system.whatever returned a value of X when it expected Y"

Comment: What is the exception's `InnerException` ?

Comment: The exception obtained is a `TargetInvocationException` with the message "A first chance exception of type 'System.Reflection.TargetInvocationException' occurred in mscorlib.dll". Visual Studio displays the Source Not Available page and there are no stack traces available either.

Comment: Side note: You have single class that mixes C# and VB implementations? Never seen such thing...

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov: No, that's not so. Like I stated in the question, it is a Visual Studio Solution which contains C# and VB.NET projects.

Comment: `SetResult` isn't failing because of the `Nothing`, is it? Can you also try it without `async`? And is calling `tcs.Task` valid after calling `tcs.SetResult(Nothing)` ?

Comment: @Rob: The actual implementation prevents running the code synchronously. Since it is asynchronous I can't break to inspect `tcs.Task`. It would have already been returned to the C# code which would be awaiting a result.

Comment: @AlexEssilfie Can you just stub out the actual implementation then, and pretend it fails? I highly doubt it's failing because of `Nothing` -> `null` - that's going to happen in almost any application with both C# and VB

Comment: Your third example doesn't make sense to me. There's no reason that `await task;` should fail, even if the result value is null. The `DoSomething()` method always returns a non-null object, so `task` itself is always non-null, and so `await task` should always be valid. The result is null, but you never bother to use it in that third example, so it being null is not a problem. Other than that, [the answer from un-lucky](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32132989) addresses your concerns: there's not a problem with `Nothing` vs `null`...you wouldn't be allowed to dereference `Nothing` in VB either!

Comment: `.ToString()` method or `await()` is not capable of handling null that's the reason for the exception you are getting.

Comment: @PeterDuniho: Sorry. I did too much redaction of the code while pasting it here. And you were right. The result is indeed `null` but I forgot to check it before trying to assign it to a variable expecting a `string`.

Answer (score 2):

This is not because of conversion from `Nothing` to `null`. Here i have some example for you where C# accepts `Nothing` as `null`:

Vb Class Library Code:

```
Public Class ClassVb
    Public Function Dosomething() As Task(Of Object)
        Return Nothing
    End Function
End Class
```

C# that Invoke This Class Library :

```
using vbclassLib;
  class Program
    {
     static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            ClassVb classLibObj = new ClassVb();
            var result = classLibObj.Dosomething();//result=null
        }
    }
```

Which works fine and gives `result=null`, ie., `Nothing is converted as null`

Let me come to your scenario:

In your scenario, when the function returns `Nothing` its definitely converted to `null` but `.ToString()` method or `await()` is not capable of handling `null` that's the reason for the exception you are getting.

- `null.ToString()` or  `(null).ToString()` says that `The operator '.' cannot be applied to operand of type '<null>'`.
- `await(null)` will not be allowed by `c#`, it says `cannot await null`.

**This may help you:**

```
ClassVb classLibObj = new ClassVb();
var temp = classLibObj.Dosomething();
var result = temp == null ? "" : temp.ToString();
```

Comment: The whole `This may help you` part can be written `var result = (new ClassVb().DoSomething() ?? "").ToString();`

Answer (score 1):

I've seen a related issue resolved by having the VB project cast 'Nothing' to the 'Object' type to ensure that it is the default value corresponding to reference types (e.g., C# null) and received by the C# project as such, instead of the default value of some value type (e.g., 0 for an integer type):

```
params.Item2.SetResult(CObj(Nothing))
```

Answer (score 0):

My error became apparent after reading un-lucky's [statement](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32132355/set-vb-net-variable-to-cs-null#32132989):

> - `null.ToString()` or `(null).ToString()` says that `The operator '.' cannot be applied to operand of type '<null>'`.
> - `await(null)` will not be allowed by c#, it says `cannot await null`.

It turns out that because I had set the `result` variable in the C# code to `string`, it was not possible to convert from `Object` (as in the VB.NET's return type of `Task(Of Object)`) without having to do a `.ToString()` or `(string)(await Method())`. Using either of these two procedures also result in a `NullReferenceException`.

I was finally able to figure out what I was doing wrong by first assigning the `Task<object>` returned to a variable and then checking its result for `null` after awaiting. Thus, I finished up with code like this which suits my purpose.

```
public class CSharpClass
{
    public async void AwaitSomething()
    {
        var task = new VbNetClass().DoSomething();
        await task;
        // test task.Result for null
        var result = (task.Result ?? "method was unsuccessful").ToString();

        // rest of code follows
    }
}
```

Thanks to [nikerym](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32132355/set-vb-net-variable-to-cs-null#comment52155460_32132355) and [Peter Duniho](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32132355/set-vb-net-variable-to-cs-null#comment52156768_32132355) for their contribution. I was too tired from staying up for over 20 hours to notice the point they were making. What beats me though is why I had a `TargetInvokationException` instead of a `NullReferenceException`.

Comment: You get `TargetInvocationException` because of the way `await` works: only the code up to the first `await` is actually in the named method where you've declared the code. The rest of the code is put into continuations (actually, a single method encapsulating a state machine), which are invoked on completion of the awaited task. If you had looked at the inner exception of the `TargetInvocationException`, you'd have seen the `NullReferenceException` that actually described what was going wrong.